# Python / Django - How to map a list of values in a dictionary to a HTML table?

Tags: python, html, django

My Django View:

```
def hub(request):

  context = {} 

  hub_id = [value['id'] for value in hub_data['data']]
  hub_name = [value['attributes']['name'] for value in hub_data['data']]
  hub_url = [value['links']['self']['href'] for value in hub_data['data']]

  nested_dict = dict(zip(hub_name, map(list, zip(hub_id, hub_url))))

  context ['rows'] = nested_dict

  return render(request, 'connector/hub.html', context)
```

The context['rows'] results in:

```
{'rows': {hub_name1 : ['hub_id1', 'hub_url1'],{hub_name2 : ['hub_id2', 'hub_url2'], etc.. }
```

I am trying to pass it a HTML table that looks like this:

```
  <th scope="col">Hub Name</th>
  <th scope="col">Hub ID</th>
  <th scope="col">Hub URL</th>
```

My tablebody looks like this:

```
  <tbody>
    {% for key, value in rows.items %}
      <tr>
        <td> {{ key }}</td>
        <td> {{ value }}</td> **//how do i just get hub_id here**
        <td> Don't know what to do here to get: hub_url </td>

      </tr>  
    {% endfor %}
  </tbody>
```

But I want to add another -tag to fill with hub_url. How do I extract the hub_id data and add it to the column: Hub ID and extract the hub_url and add it to the column Hub URL.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Why not pass `hub_data` to the template and do the lookups in the template?

Comment: The hub_data is even further nested, I could not get that to work, but the approach would be the same I imagine. I just don't know how :)

Comment: I suppose the data you've provided for context['rows'] is incorrect or incomplete.. Could you correct that ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass the data to the template without transforming it

```
return render(request, 'connector/hub.html', {'data': hub_data['data']})
```

And then lookup the attributes using the "dot" template syntax for each row

```
<tbody>
  {% for row in data %}
    <tr>
      <td>{{ row.attributes.name }}</td>
      <td>{{ row.id }}</td>
      <td>{{ row.links.self.href }}</td>
    </tr>  
  {% endfor %}
</tbody>
```

Comment: This is exactly the solution to my problem. Now I understand the iterations much better.